# Push notification in IBM-Mobilefirst unexpected error

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I run the push notification sample provided by the IBM-MobileFirst in device. And i'm getting error "UNEXPECTED-ERROR".

Please find the attached screenshot for reference.

[image]

Let me know did i miss any configuration? And also please guide what adapter used in this project (Java adapter,HTTP adapter or javascript adapter)

Edited:

I downloaded the sample from the [link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_gettingstarted.html) under  "Push notification" category

And when i open the application i am getting server unable to process error 
[image]

Edited:

1. I am using Worklight version 7.1.0 and eclipse Juno SR2
2. I downloaded sample from the [link](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/start/c_gettingstarted.html)
3. I just import the application that i downloaded from the link to eclipse IDE. Having android environment and js, html files in application.

Comment: HTTP Status = 500. Internal Server error. There is an issue on the server, or it cannot handle the data you sent. That is not something that we can really answer without seeing your code, though

Comment: @cricket_007 As I mentioned this is the code from IBM-MobileFirst Sample push notification. I didn't add/edit/update any code in that project. I just downloaded and ran the application in android device. Don't know where the code contains server call

Comment: How about mentioning your mobilefirst version, if this is a Cordova or native app, a link to the sample and mention how you setup your sample. Do you really expect everyone to understand what you've done?

Comment: You're probably missing some API key, if I were to guess

Comment: @cricket_007 I added API Key in config "application-descriptor.xml"

Comment: Please read my questions again. You did not answer any of them.

Comment: @IdanAdar Sorry for that, i added the details for your questions

Answer (score 0):

1. You say you're using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1, but you've downloaded the sample for Worklight 6.0.
2. You also failed to repeatedly answers the questions you've been asked, specifically whether this is a native or Hybrid sample. But anyway, this seems to be the sample you're looking for: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/event-source-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/
3. You mentioned that you only tried running it without any setup, then how do you expect it to work? Since this is Android you also need to create a server key and senderId. Please read the documentation: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/notifications/push-notifications-overview/push-notifications-in-hybrid-applications/

Comment: Thanks for the links, I downloaded from github and changed the GCM key and GCM id in the source. I ran the application in android device now i'm getting the error "Failed connecting to MobileFirst Server. Try again later".

Comment: have you verified the host you are trying to connect to in wlclient.properties?